# How to get the Crowns on World 6-5?

Tags: boxboy-2

How can I get the second crown in World 6-5? This game is rather new so I couldn't find any tutorials online. Here's a picture just in case, and the hint with it.

[image: The crown]

[image: The hint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: solution]

i figure you already got it, but if not, stand on the 3rd block, and build the 1st section and then the 2nd